# Cosmos Query Where Clause Issue in Postman

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I can not get the Body to return results when using a where clause.  It doesn't seem to like the values for f.RequestPath.

```
{      
    "query": "SELECT * FROM AppLogs f WHERE f.RequestPath in ("/payments/post-sales", "/payments/pre-sales", "/payments/refunds", "/payments", "/Payments")"
}
```

[image: Postman Error Message After adding Where clause]

The Query works when just do this.  I think it might have something to do with the slashes in the Requestpath values but don't know how to resolve that.  Do you need to use escape characters?  How would you do that?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
{      
    "query": "SELECT * FROM AppLogs f WHERE 1=1"
}
```

[image: Query Works without the Where clause for Request Path]

Comment: Don’t you need to escape the / in the json? Like so // ?

Comment: Please edit to include properly formatted text instead of images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 2):

Please try by replacing double quotes in your query with single quotes. Something like:

```
{      
    "query": "SELECT * FROM AppLogs f WHERE f.RequestPath in ('/payments/post-sales', '/payments/pre-sales', '/payments/refunds', '/payments', '/Payments')"
}
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned by @MatiasQuaranta in the comments, you can also escape the double quotes in you query by doing something like:

```
"query": "SELECT * FROM AppLogs f WHERE f.RequestPath in (\"/payments/post-sales\", \"/payments/pre-sales\", \"/payments/refunds\", \"/payments\", \"/Payments\")"
```

Comment: Alternatively they can be escaped `"query": "SELECT * FROM AppLogs f WHERE f.RequestPath in (\"/payments/post-sales\", \"/payments/pre-sales\", \"/payments/refunds\", \"/payments\", \"/Payments\")"`